# How run hbm2ddl with maven/hibernate4

Tags: hibernate, maven-3, hbm2ddl

I'd been using the de.juplo mvn plugin but that appears to be abandoned and has been crashing randomly. I'm thinking that there surely should be a best practice for running hbm2ddl but I've been stumped by the documentation (or lack thereof).

Answer (score 0):

I think all the tools are using legacy hibernate version (3.x), but there is a new player. Take a look at project:

https://github.com/Devskiller/hbm2ddl-maven-plugin

It is using Hibernate 5.2, so maybe it suits your needs.